# How to use admin privileges to save files (from notepad)?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, administrator, privileges

Whenever I try to save a file to a system folder (from Notepad, if that matters) it gives me an error message box that simply says "Acess is denied.", even though I am an administrator.

So to edit files in system folders (ex: startup folder) I have to move the file to a non-protected folder (such as my desktop), edit the file, then move it back.  This process can get *really* annoying!

Is there any way I can keep it from denying me access to system folders when saving files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on notepad and "Run as Administrator"

Comment: < *Facepalm* >  I'll accept as soon as it let's me in 10 minutes.

Comment: Do I have to open elevated notepad first then open it through that, or is there a way I can open the file from the file explorer (i.e. right click the file > *Open With/Edit*) with elevated privileges?

Comment: You can use the `Send to` menu: create a shortcut pointing to `notepad` in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` and edit its properties to set `Run this program as an administrator` in the `Compatability` tab. You may already have a shortcut for `notepad` there, in which case copy it and rename it to `Notepad - Admin` for the edited properties.